# Combination of .load and .post?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, jquery-post

Basically, I want to load the content of a page, while also passing it some POST parameters.

Now, you may say, I use `.post`, and then just use something like `$("#div").html(data)`, but the problem is I want the functionality of the only-select-one-element thing in `.load`. Can that be used with `.post` somehow, perhaps?

Comment: nice question. I would like to know the answer too.

Comment: It's possible. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>No, there is no method for loading content with a POST request.</strike>

You can make a POST request and place the result in the page. Example:

```
$.post(
  'page.html',
  { post: 'data' },
  function(data){
    $('#someElement').html(data);
  },
  'html'
);
```

#### Edit:

To use a partial result of the returned code, you can parse the result just as the `load` method does:

```
  function(data){
    var c = $(data);
    $('#someElement').append(c.find('#somePart'));
  },
```

#### Edit 2:

As Jack showed, there is actually a way to make the `load` method make a POST request. (I missed it because of the misleading documentation.)

Example with a partial use of the result, sending the data as an object triggers the POST request method:

```
$('"someElement #somePart').load('page.html', { post: 'data' });
```

Comment: then in that case, is it possible to put a certain part of `data` (i.e. a certain element or set of elements) into `$('#someElement')`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.load()` in this manner to pass `POST` data:

```
var data = {
    a: '123'
}

$('#element').load(url, data);
```

If only two parameters are used and the second parameter is an object it will use `POST` and pass the contents to the page to load.

See also: [`.load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method)

Comment: @Guffa Then you may have missed the `Request method` section of that page - http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that section. I wasn't even looing for it, because it totally contradicts the first section of the documentation where it clearly states that it does roughly the same thing as the `$.get` method.